# Uses of PreserveExistingDefaults?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

Why and when should we use PreserveExistingDefaults during autofac registration?

I have read it's uses form Autoface docs:
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html

But my question is, when is the case we will register multiple implementation with single interface.

Can anybody give some example from real time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be use when you want to register a new implementation without changing the default one. When you register multiple registration for a single interface, *Autofac* will resolve all of them when you try to register `IEnumerable<IService>`

Let say you have 2 implementations of `IService`

```
interface IService { }
class Service1 : IService { }
class Service2 : IService { }
```

If you register them like this :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Service1>().As<IService>();
builder.RegisterType<Service2>().As<IService>().PreserveExistingDefaults();

IContainer container = builder.Build();

IService service = container.Resolve<IService>();  // will be Service1

List<IService> services = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IService>>().ToList();
services[0]; // => Service1 
services[1]; // => Service2 or the opposite, there is no warranty on the order
```

You will obtain `Service1` when you resolve `IService` but you will resolve both of them when you resolve `IEnumerable<IService>`

By the way, it is really exceptional to use it. I don't remember having ever used it. It is always simpler to use [Named and Keyed services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

Comment: But then How will I use Service2?