# Autofac register default class with generics

Tags: c#, generics, autofac, mediator

In Autofac want to register a class as a default if no other implementation of a generic type is found. That is if have AAAAuditer class:

```
public class AAAAuditer : DefaultAuditer<Command, Response>
```

then when I resolve the interface want to get an instance of AAAAuditer

but if don't declare AAAAuditer should get injected and instance DefaultAuditer

The point is not to have to define an empty AAAAuditer if it is not doing anything different than the default.

Tried:

```
        builder
            .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Auditer<,>))
            .As(typeof(IAuditer<,>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IAuditer<,>)))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

but this gives me DefaultAuditer even if have AAAAuditer register

Also tried this too but also gives me the default

```
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IAuditer<,>)))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder
        .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Auditer<,>))
        .As(typeof(IAuditer<,>))
        .IfNotRegistered(typeof(Auditer<,>))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

another complication is that I am using the MediatR library that uses this to register parameters for the mediator pipeline

```
    builder.Register<SingleInstanceFactory>(ctx =>
    {
        var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return t => c.TryResolve(t, out var o) ? o : null;
    });
```

and then

```
public class MediatorPipeline<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IAsyncRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    ...
    ...
    public MediatorPipeline(
        IAsyncRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> innerHandler,
        IAuditer<TRequest, TResponse> auditer,
```

any ideas how can I do what want?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Looks like i'm running into the same issue

Comment: @MarkB did not make it work the way I wanted. At the end left the first block of code in this post and gave and implementation for each combination IAuditer<in TRequest, in TResponse>. Using a base class as DefaultAuditer from where 'void' implementations inherit and if need something particular implement the IAuditer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to make use of `PreserveExistingDefaults`, but that apparently does not work when making use of RegisterGeneric

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891744/uses-of-preserveexistingdefaults